# Authentication for root process not showing all users

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sudo, authentication, root

I have 2 linux machines, 1 VPS and 1 raspberry pi

**Problem:**

When calling a root function e.g. `service "a service" restart` both these cases appear different. Some users do not show as possible auth users even though they are in both cases sudoers

**VPS:**

```
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  user1
 2.  cybex
 3.  ,,, (backup-user)
 4.  steam
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-4):
```

**Raspberry Pi**

user1 and cybex are both users and sudoers (users are in sudoers file and part of sudo group), but they are not listed.

```
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/nano' as the super user
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  ,,, (pi)
 2.  root
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2):
```

Why would this happen and be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, currently sudoers isn't only way to control user privileges on Linux distros. possibly you have polkit based authentication.

To set an user cybex as an administrator for polkit, create a file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/99-cybex.conf`

containing:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:cybex
```

that should help, but configuration depends on your Distro, so try to read `polkit` man page or also check [this](https://www.hogarthuk.com/?q=node/10) or [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) links or google it key name together with your Distro name.

Answer (score 0):

add yourself to the group `sudo`, in file `/etc/group`